# SWreveal segue identifier based on language

Tags: swift, xcode, segue, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm working on a 2 languages app (En-He), and Hebrew is a rtl language, I have a problem with SWreveal as I'm trying to make it appear from left on English and right on Hebrew, I made two segues (sw_rear and sw_right) and I wrote this code

```
let lang = Locale.current.languageCode

    if self.revealViewController() != nil {
        if (lang == "he") {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.rightRevealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        } else {
            menuButton.target = self.revealViewController()
            menuButton.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
            self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        }

    }
```

The menuButton works pretty fine, but if you're using GestureRecognizer to navigate the menu you'll be able to navigate the left and the right one at the same time because there are two segues, I don't know if there's a way to make it only one segue and set it's identifier through app delegate or something like that

Comment: Are you talking about the Sliding Menu like this? http://designwoop.com/2014/12/25-sliding-hamburger-menus-app-ui-inspiration/

Comment: @Fangming Yes exactly

Comment: Ok. And you are doing everything by yourself from scratch? Or using some public SDK?

Comment: @Fangming
I'm using a famous library called SWrevealViewController

Comment: Ok... Im pretty confused by your approach but what are you trying to achieve here? Are you creating two menus with different languages?